# AutoScraper doesn't pick up some information

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am using the following code to test out scrapping rightmove to check AutoScraper's functionalities. However on the website [link below] it is not able to read the Flat", bathroom or bedroom number. A sample code is provided below and any fix or alternative will be great.

https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-to-rent/find.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%5E70403&propertyTypes=&includeLetAgreed=false&mustHave=&dontShow=&furnishTypes=&keywords=

```
url_to_scrape="https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-to-rent/find.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%5E70403&propertyTypes=&includeLetAgreed=false&mustHave=&dontShow=&furnishTypes=&keywords=" WantedList=["West End Gate, W2","£4,117 pcm","£950 pw"]

Scraper = AutoScraper() 
ScrapedData = Scraper.build(url_to_scrape, wanted_list=WantedList)
print(ScrapedData)
```

Comment: Many sites require using an automated web browser with a JavaScript engine.  See: https://github.com/alirezamika/autoscraper/issues/71